# .value on form group shows numeric values as null or ""

Tags: javascript, angular

im having trouble getting data from a form group. I have this formGroup called `lineitemForm`, and I'm wanting to format said form group in the following:

```
  private formatTransferData() {
    const depositDates = this.getDepositDates(this.lineItemsForm);
    const mappedValues = this.formatFormValues(depositDates);

    return this.filterFormValues(mappedValues);
  }

  private formatFormValues(depositDates) {
    return depositDates.map((depositDate) => {
      return {
        effectiveDates: depositDate.controls.effectiveDates.value,
        depositDate: depositDate.controls.depositDate.value,
      };
    });
  }
```

I have been noticing that the function `formatTransferData()` breaks down when I pass `depositDates` into `this.FormatValues()`, there are two numeric variables inside of `depositDates`, I can console.log inside the mapping `depositDate.controls.effectiveDates` and see two numeric values, but as soon as I add on the `.value` to the end the numeric values either resolve themselves to `null` or a simple `""`, is there some sort of conflict that I am unaware of when using `.value` on a formGroup that contains numeric value/s?

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: So the dates are `numeric` values? What type of controls are they then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On later reflection, the best way to go about getting values from a formGroup is by doing the following:

```
this.formGroup.controls['someFormGroupValue'].value
```

or

```
this.someForm.get('someFormItem').value;
```